# why this pangram program is not working?

Tags: c, arrays

It's a panagram program almost correct but I don't get why it isn't working?

```
int main() {

    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */  
    char *a=malloc(256);
    int first[26]={0},c=0,i=0,flag=0;
    //printf("Enter string");
    fgets (a, MAX_NAME_SZ, stdin);
    while(a[c]!='\0')
    {
        first[a[c]-'a']++;
        c++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    {   
        if(first[i]==0)
        {
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(flag==0)
    {
        printf("panagram");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("not panagram");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does *it isn't working?* mean ? Do you get any errors ?

Comment: Please state what problems you are facing, or post your error message along with your question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions.

Comment: There are no errors in code. I meant the logic isn't working.

Comment: Whats data is in you file?What is your expected ouput?What are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical mistake in your code because you did not do any input validation and/or sanity checking on the user input.

In your code,

```
 first[a[c]-'a']++;
```

tries to access invalid memory location in `first` array if `a[c]` is not in the range of `[a, z]`.

Even for an user input of `UPPER` case letter or a *space* [] *(which all, logically should be considered valid input)*, you program expericence [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by accesing out-of-bound memory.

To avoid that, perform a check on `a[c]` value before directly using that as an index of `first` array.